# select a combinations of radio buttons from different groups

Tags: javascript, html

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById("whole").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("proto").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("peakpro").style.display = "none";

document.getElementById("myform").onsubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var bandSelected = document.querySelector("input[name=band]:checked").value;
  var channelSelected = document.querySelector("input[name=channel]:checked").value;
  var appSelected = document.querySelector("input[name=app]:checked").value;
  
  if(bandSelected == "alpha" && channelSelected == "1" && appSelected == null) {
    document.getElementById("whole").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("proto").style.display = "block";
  }
   if(appSelected == "peakperformance" && channelSelected == null && bandSelected == null) {
    document.getElementById("whole").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("peakpro").style.display = "block";
 }
  
  //console.log("Band Selected: ", bandSelected, ", Channel Selected: ", channelSelected);
};

});
```

I'm working on a project in which I have to select a combination of radio buttons from different panels to perform a specific task. For example I have one set of radio buttons named bands and a second set named channels , when I select 1st option from band and 1st option from channels and then click submit button a specific task is performed.And when I select a different combination, a different task will be performed. How it can be done?

```html
<div id="whole">
 <div id="bands">
  <h2>Select Band</h2>
     <input type="checkbox" name="band">Alpha<br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="band">Beta<br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="band">Gamma<br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="band">Theta<br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="band">Delta<br>
 </div>
 <div id="channel">
  <h2>Select channel</h2>
  <input type="checkbox" name="channel"> Channel 1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="channel"> Channel 2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="channel"> Channel 3<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="channel"> Channel 4<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="channel"> Channel 5<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="channel"> Channel 6<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="channel"> Channel 7<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="channel"> Channel 8<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="channel"> Channel 9<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="channel"> Channel 10<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="channel"> Channel 11<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="channel"> Channel 12<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="channel"> Channel 13<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="channel"> Channel 14<br>
 </div>
 <button type="submit" id="subtest" onclick>Submit</button>
 <div id="app">
  <h2>Training Applications</h2>
            <input type="radio" name="app">ADHD<br>
            <input type="radio" name="app">Stress<br>
            <input type="radio" name="app">Anxiety<br>
            <input type="radio" name="app">Peak Performance<br>
            <!--<button type="submit" id="subapp">Submit</button>-->
 </div>
 
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you please add your code?

Comment: Where and how you need to submit the task?

Comment: @uday8486 like changing a div on a submit button click..basically i want to show a different div on every new combination of radiobuttons/checkbox

Comment: @JonathanIrvin done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your description mentions radio buttons and not checkboxes, I converted channels and bands to radio buttons. You are going to want to wrap everything in a `form` tag. You want to listen for the form submit event, get the selected channel and band values, and do what you need to do depending on what the values are.

```js
document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var bandSelected = document.querySelector("input[name=band]:checked");
  var channelSelected = document.querySelector("input[name=channel]:checked");
  var appSelected = document.querySelector("input[name=app]:checked");
  
  if(bandSelected != null && bandSelected.value == "Gamma" && channelSelected != null && channelSelected.value == "1") {
    console.log("Do something special here");
  }
  
  if(bandSelected == null && channelSelected == null && appSelected != null && appSelected.value == "Peak Performance") {
    console.log("hide or show div");
    // show
    // document.getElementById("yourDiv").style.display = "block";
    // hide
    // document.getElementById("yourDiv").style.display = "none";
  }

};
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
 <div id="whole">
  <div id="bands">
   <h2>Select Band</h2>
      <input type="radio" value="Alpha" name="band">Alpha<br>
      <input type="radio" value="Beta" name="band">Beta<br>
      <input type="radio" value="Gamma" name="band">Gamma<br>
      <input type="radio" value="Theta" name="band">Theta<br>
      <input type="radio" value="Delta" name="band">Delta<br>
  </div>
  <div id="channel">
   <h2>Select channel</h2>
   <input type="radio" value="1" name="channel"> Channel 1<br>
   <input type="radio" value="2" name="channel"> Channel 2<br>
   <input type="radio" value="3" name="channel"> Channel 3<br>
   <input type="radio" value="4" name="channel"> Channel 4<br>
   <input type="radio" value="5" name="channel"> Channel 5<br>
   <input type="radio" value="6" name="channel"> Channel 6<br>
   <input type="radio" value="7" name="channel"> Channel 7<br>
   <input type="radio" value="8" name="channel"> Channel 8<br>
   <input type="radio" value="9" name="channel"> Channel 9<br>
   <input type="radio" value="10" name="channel"> Channel 10<br>
   <input type="radio" value="11" name="channel"> Channel 11<br>
   <input type="radio" value="12" name="channel"> Channel 12<br>
   <input type="radio" value="13" name="channel"> Channel 13<br>
   <input type="radio" value="14" name="channel"> Channel 14<br>
  </div>
  
  <div id="app">
   <h2>Training Applications</h2>
    <input type="radio" value="ADHD" name="app">ADHD<br>
    <input type="radio" value="Stress" name="app">Stress<br>
    <input type="radio" value="Anxiety" name="app">Anxiety<br>
    <input type="radio" value="Peak Performance" name="app">Peak Performance<br>
                <button type="submit" id="subtest" onclick>Submit</button>
  </div>
   </div>

          <div id="proto">
  <h1>Select Protocol</h1>
  <input type="radio" name="pro" value="increase">Increase Alpha<br>
  <input type="radio" name="pro" value="reduce">Reduce Alpha<br>
 </div>

 <div id="peakpro">
  <h1>Select Protocol</h1>
  <h2>Improvement of Attention</h2>
    <input type="radio" name="Attention" value="incbeta">Increase Beta<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Attention" value="redtheta">Reduce Theta<br>
  <h2>Improvement of Relaxation</h2>
    <input type="radio" name="Relaxation" value="incalpha">Increase Alpha<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Relaxation" value="inctheta">Increase Theta<br>
  <h2>Assistance with Meditation</h2>
    <input type="radio" name="Meditation" value="inalpha">Increase Alpha<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Meditation" value="intheta">Increase Theta<br>
 </div>

  </form>
```

Comment: Does that help? If so, can you mark the answer as correct? If not, can you let me know what questions you have?

Comment: I got it. Being a little more specified I have 2 divs . When I select channel 1 and Alpha band  div 1 i.e proto should be shown and when I select Peak performance from training application solely div 1 will be hide and div 2 i.e peak pro should be shown. i have added the code of divs from a new page .How it can be done using javascript

Comment: Glad that worked for you! To hide, you can get the div by the id and set the display to none example: ( `document.getElementById("peakpro").style.display = "none";` ) and to show again, you set the display to block ( example: `document.getElementById("peakpro").style.display = "block";` )

Comment: Thankyou it worked. But there is one little problem. As i have told earlier when i select channel 1 and alpha band it should show div 1 and when I select only peak performance and no option from other two so it is showing error that it is not getting null values. I also specified null value but still not working. I'm also adding my modified JS code

Comment: You have to check to make sure something is actually checked (and not null) before you try to get the value. I updated the code.

Comment: Take a look at the code that I updated and run it and you will see that there aren't any errors. The null checks prevent any null errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203539/discussion-between-jonathan-irvin-and-maryam-nadeem).